# ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 11 and input n_features is 2

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, data-science

While running the below code in jupyter notebook, I am getting the value error.

> ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 11 and input n_features is 2

How to resolve this issue?

```
# Visualising the Training set results
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
X_set, y_set = X_train, y_train
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
```

I am getting the below error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-bc13e66e79fe> in <module>
      4 X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
      5                      np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
----> 6 plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
      7              alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
      8 plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py in predict(self, X)
    627             The predicted classes.
    628         """
--> 629         proba = self.predict_proba(X)
    630 
    631         if self.n_outputs_ == 1:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py in predict_proba(self, X)
    671         check_is_fitted(self)
    672         # Check data
--> 673         X = self._validate_X_predict(X)
    674 
    675         # Assign chunk of trees to jobs

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py in _validate_X_predict(self, X)
    419         check_is_fitted(self)
    420 
--> 421         return self.estimators_[0]._validate_X_predict(X, check_input=True)
    422 
    423     @property

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in _validate_X_predict(self, X, check_input)
    394         n_features = X.shape[1]
    395         if self.n_features_ != n_features:
--> 396             raise ValueError("Number of features of the model must "
    397                              "match the input. Model n_features is %s and "
    398                              "input n_features is %s "

ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 11 and input n_features is 2
```

Full Model Code: https://github.com/anandsinha07/Placement-prediction-system-using-ML-algos/blob/master/PREDICTION-Random%20Forest%20Classification/random_forest_classification.py

Comment: Your model (`classifier`) was trained for having 11 number in each X input. But you feed it 2 numbers. I.e. your array for prediction `np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T` has just two columns, but should have 11.

Comment: We can investigate the problem if you provide your code of the model.

Comment: Alternatively you can create 11 columns by having same like above but 11 Xs, like X1, X2, X3... X11, better as array of cause.

Comment: @Arty Kindly check the Full Model Code From here --> https://github.com/anandsinha07/Placement-prediction-system-using-ML-algos/blob/master/PREDICTION-Random%20Forest%20Classification/random_forest_classification.py

Comment: Yes, in your code you're training model to predict column 12 by columns 1-11. Hence in the last part of code when you're visualizing and predicting (when you have exception) you're providing just two columns X1, X2, but need to provide 11 columns.

Comment: Same way like you create X1 and X2, samely you need to create 11 columns in total, i.e. X1, X2, X3... X11. But of cause create them in a loop and store in list.

Comment: I think I know what you're trying to achieve. You want to Plot 3D contour plot of prediction of column 12 by columns 1-2, where columns 1-2 are generated by uniform stepping in min/max range. In order to do that you need somehow to provide other columns as well, e.g. by passing in average values of training set.

Comment: I'll try to fix your code now the way I think is reasonable.

Comment: Posted my [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64197285/941531).

Comment: Please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed), and it should *not* be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter (edited out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll fixed your code the way I understand the problem, several extra lines added. Main problem is that you only feed columns 1 and 2 for prediction, but predictor expects 11 columns 1-11. Hence columns 3-11 should be filled somehow. At least you can fill them with zeros.

In my solution I sorted training set by 1st column and then when building meshgrid with I try to approximate columns 3-11 needed for prediction by finding nearest column 1 value that has value near X1 from meshgrid. I.e. I'm trying to find the best approximation for columns 3-11 given only column 1, this is just not to fill columns 3-11 with zeros, which also could be done.

Also I commented line `#from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split` and replaced it with `from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split` because first line uses old sklearn library, in new version only the second line works, sub-module name was changed. Choose the correct variant of this line for yourself.

```
# Random Forest Classification

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('finalplacementdata3.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, range(1, 12)].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 12].values

siX = np.lexsort((X[:, 1], X[:, 0]))
sX, sy = X[siX], y[siX]

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
#from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

# Fitting Random Forest Classification to the Training set
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 10, criterion = 'entropy', random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

# Making the Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

# Visualising the Training set results
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
X_set, y_set = X_train, y_train
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
                     
riX = np.minimum(sX.shape[0] - 1, np.searchsorted(sX[:, 0], X1.ravel()))
rX = X[riX]

plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()] + list(rX[:, 2:].T)).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
plt.title('Random Forest Classification (Training set)')
plt.xlabel('Quants')
plt.ylabel('CGPA')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Visualising the Test set results
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
X_set, y_set = X_test, y_test
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))

riX = np.minimum(sX.shape[0] - 1, np.searchsorted(sX[:, 0], X1.ravel()))
rX = X[riX]

plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()] + list(rX[:, 2:].T)).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
plt.title('Random Forest Classification (Test set)')
plt.xlabel('Quants')
plt.ylabel('CGPA')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```